# Connection could not be established with host mail.gandi.net

Tags: laravel, email

So basically I'm trying to send a mail through smtp.

My configuration is the following one :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.gandi.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=webmaster@xxxx.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxx
```

I tried it in a local environnement and it worked perfectly fine. However, when I'm putting it in production I'm ending up with this error :

> local.ERROR: Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host mail.gandi.net [Connection timed out #110]

I tried to change the port from 587 to 25 thinking it could be due to FAI but nothing worked.

Does someone as an idea of where this could be coming from ?

### EDIT

On dev server :

```
$ telnet mail.gandi.net 587
Trying 2001:4b98:c:521::11...
```

On prod server :

```
$ telnet mail.gandi.net 587
Trying 217.70.184.11...
Connected to mail.gandi.net.
Escape character is '^]'.

220 relay.mail.gandi.net ESMTP Postfix (edited)
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems the host is wrong. For me it works like this:

```
MAIL_HOST=ssl://mail.gandi.net
MAIL_PORT=465
```

Comment: I agree an SSL connection is better, but I can connect to mail.gandi.net port 587 fine from here without SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Is your production server behind a firewall of some sort? Try to telnet to the host an the port and see if you can connect.

If you can't and there is no way to open a connection, I suggest to use Mailgun for your sending needs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#driver-prerequisites

Comment: So i've tried to telnet it but every port are blocked in dev server any idea.

Comment: Use Laravel's Mailgun API then! This way, all messages are sent through the API instead of SMTP.